# Why do Suggested Edit Review audits often use the same user?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, review-audits

Whenever I get a Suggested Edit Review test, the proposed edit appears to always come from the same user account. The account belongs to a legitimate, albeit new, [user](https://superuser.com/users/214429/torben-f).

This brings up a couple of things:

- It's a little unfair to regularly propose to other users that a single user consistently makes [daft](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/103200) edits. It could also be argued that it's unfair to ever falsely suggest that any real user has proposed a bad edit.
- It's very easy to spot tests!